# Proving $g^{zh} (q) = g^x (q)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble following one of the proofs in Stalling's textbook. In the proof, q is a prime, and h, z, x are integers in Z/qZ s.t.

gcd(h, q - 1) = 1, and

zh = x (q - 1), and

g is a generator of Z/qZ.

He says it follows that $g^{zh} (q) = g^x (q)$. I believe he is invoking Euler's theorem, but I don't quite see how this exactly follows.

Comment: Do you mean $a\equiv b\pmod q$ with $a(q)=b(q)$?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose when you write $zh=x(q-1)$ you meant $zh \equiv x \pmod{q-1}$.
You don't even need the condition that $g$ is generator. It's true for all $\gcd (g,q)=1$.

Note that by Euler's theorem then $g^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$. So if $zh=x+(q-1)k$ for some integer $k$ then $$g^{zh}= g^x \cdot g^{(q-1)k} \equiv g^x \pmod{q},$$ all because $g^{(q-1)k}=(g^{q-1})^k \equiv 1^k \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$.